# Mifare Classic 1k write keys

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I'm trying to make an Android application to write NFC tags. To see how to do that, I've downloaded an example. However, the example does not work. It says it can't authenticate. That can only mean that it uses an incorrect key for this type of card. The strange thing is, even the `KEY_DEFAULT` and `KEY_MIFARE_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY` keys are not working on my blank cards. Did Mifare change the keys in any way?

EDIT: here's my code.

```
            /* Authenticate the MAD Sector, sector 1, with key A */
        succes = mClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(
                1, key);
        if (succes) {
            /* Authentication succeeded */

            /*
             * This will read a 16-byte block in this sector
             * It is an I/O operation and will block until complete.
             * It must not be called from the main application thread.
             **/
            b.append(mClassic.readBlock(1), 0, 16);
            b.append(mClassic.readBlock(2), 0, 16);
            b.append(mClassic.readBlock(3), 0, 16);
            data = b.toByteArray();
        }
        /* Authentication failed */
        else
            sb.append("Authentication failed");
        mClassic.close();

    }
```

I've tried it with the following keys already:

```
MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT
MifareClassic.KEY_MIFARE_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY
00 00 00 00 00 00
ff ff ff ff ff ff
```

all to no avail..

Comment: refer to this blog: http://nearfieldcommunication.com/developers/android/ http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.jp/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.htmlHope this will help you in gud understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Ubiqconn Tablet PC. First thing I would do is to check whether the NFC implementation in the device actually supports MIFARE. In your main activity's `onCreate()` add:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  ...
  if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("com.nxp.mifare")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "No MIFARE support!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: Guess what... `No MIFARE support!` Thank you for your help, now i'm gonna tell my boss that he ordered 200 wrong tags lol.

Comment: Interesting. I googled for the device and the manufacturer's website seems to claim they support MIFARE. So I wonder what is going on.

Comment: You mention that the device runs 2.3.4. The [Android Compatibility Device Description](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-2.3-cdd.pdf) of 2.3 does not mention "com.nxp.mifare", while the [CDD for 4.1](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd.pdf) does. Some may be there is still hope.

Comment: I sent the manufacturer an e-mail about this. Now I'll have to wait for his reply.

Comment: The manufacturer claims that his device does indeed support Mifare 1k/4k and Ultralight, just as the website says. Is it possible that despite the fact that `com.nxp.mifare` is not mentioned it should be working just fine, and my error lies somewhere else? Or will upgrading my Android version solve the problem?

Comment: I doubt that you can upgrade Android on the device. Perhaps the problem is with your code after all. Could you add the relevant part of the code to your question?

Comment: Sector counting starts from 0. You are trying to access the wrong blocks. Blocks 0, 1, 2, 3 are in sector 0.

Comment: Aha. And sector 1 contains blocks 4, 5, 6, 7? It wasn't clear to me that the blockcount was cumulative..

Comment: But still, that doesn't explain why authenticating the sector fails. All sectors use the same key.

Comment: When authenticating sector 1 and then trying to access blocks in sector 0, the access will always fail (even if the keys are the same for both sectors).

Comment: I know, but that is not where it fails. It never actually reaches the part inside the then-part of the if-statement.

Comment: I just noticed you are located in the Netherlands. Perhaps you have an OV-chipkaart or can borrow one. This would provide you with a card with a known key: key A of sector 0 of such a card is the all-zero key.

Comment: Ah yes i have one. It's the same chip indeed ;) When i set the key to twelve zeroes, using `private byte[] key = {(byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0', (byte)'0'};` it ends up being twelve times `48`. What causes this?

Comment: A MIFARE key is only 6 bytes long: `byte[] key = {0,0,0,0,0,0};` should do it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Keys show up properly now though, as 000000

Answer (score 1):

Either you have bug in your app(s), or the keys have been customized. Use an app like NFC [TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo) to check whether you can read/write the cards with default keys. If it doesn't work, contact whoever sold you the cards and ask them what are the keys.

Comment: I can't install apps from the Play Store, because my testing device is rooted and does not have Play Store / Google Account linked to it.

Comment: In that case try to read your cards with a desktop reader or a different Android device that has Google Play installed. BTW, being rooted doesn't prevent you from using the Play Store. What device are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Ubiqconn Tablet PC running Android 2.3.4 . Google Play can indeed be installed, but somehow it is impossible to add a Google Account to the device. Settings --> Accounts and Synchronisation --> Add account only allows Microsoft Exchange accounts for some reason.

I do not have a desktop NFC-reader here.

Comment: If it is not an official 'Google experience' (or whatever it is called nowadays) device with Google services (including Play/Market) pre-installed, getting Google Play to work is a hack and may or may not work.